# Showing another grid inside one cell of the kendo grid

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

I am using a kendo grid to display my data. I want to show another kendo grid inside one cell of my kendo grid. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'way' (using the ["template" option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template) of the corresponding Grid column), however I would suggest to instead use Grid hierarchy to show details about current row:

- [Grid: hierarchy demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy)

Nesting another Grid inside cells of current Grid is not a good idea as it will not be usable, it will reduce the page performance etc.